How to derive the Penrose coordinates for a BTZ black hole
I come across this metric when reading a paper
$$
d s^2=\frac{\ell^2\left(-d s^2+d y^2\right)+r_h^2 \cos ^2 s d \phi^2}{\cos ^2 y}, \quad s, y \in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$
Does anyone know how to derive this Penrose coordinates for BTZ black hole?

"reading a paper" Which paper?
